# Add new div every 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

The focus is on the `else` bit, I am adding a div  `$('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');`, I need to check if I already added 3 divs, and if so, add a new `$('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);` and then start again

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $('#content').removeAttr('id');
    var $row = $el.closest('.row-fluid');
    if($row.next('.new').length){
        $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');
    }
    else {
         $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
         $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');
    }
});
```

Comment: check if you added 3 divs where? Could use a better explanation of what could should be doing. A demo in jsfiddle.net would realy help

Comment: as the question says, I need to check if I already added 3 divs, what div and where it has been said: $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new'); and that in the "else" bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this:

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function() {
var $el = $(this);
$('#content').removeAttr('id');
var $row = $el.closest('.row-fluid');
var $rowNew = $row.next('.new');

if ($rowNew.children().length >= 3) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
}

if($row.next('.new').length){
        $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');
}
else {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
        $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this using modulus (Operators/Modulus.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040_Operators/Modulus.htm):

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $('#content').removeAttr('id');
    var $row = $el.closest('.row-fluid');

    var count = $('.new').find('span4').length;

    if (count % 3 == 0)
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);

    if($row.next('.new').length){
        $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');
    }
    else {
         $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
         $('<div id="content" class="span4"></div>').appendTo('.new');
    }
});
```

This is rough and probably needs some massaging, but I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: yes I thought of using modules but young on jquery here :) Do you mind polishing it?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you're aware that you're using appending duplicate ids to your code.

Comment: Modulus is straight up JavaScript, has nothing to do with jQuery.  You should mess around with it to get a better feel.

Comment: I am removing the ids with the click: $('#content').removeAttr('id'); I need to use the id for other thigns (ajax) but once they loaded and printed I can remove it, that's what I do on a click each time. SO literally in the html I will only have 1 id at the end.

Comment: Ok.  I updated the example so the code appears in the correct place.  This should work for you.

Comment: It is adding '<div class="row-fluid new"></div>'

Comment: don't we have to add a counter++ ?

Comment: No. What the count is doing is getting the amount of span4 in the new class with each pass, so it should auto increment. We're then checking if that number is a multiple of 3. When you debug through it, what is count each time?

Comment: I think I see the issue. Try looking for the closet new class before you do the find.

Comment: could you update? also.. after the 3 span divs, should I not add a new row just after the .new div rather than $row? But maybe not, maybe it is better to post a new row on top of the prev row so it will push content down and with have no scrolling

Comment: I can't update currently, writing from my phone. Please post what you have in jsfiddle and we can get this cleaned up.

Comment: wanted to add the site but it uses ajax to load those divs so I can jsfiddle

Comment: tried this with no luck "$el.closest('.row-fluid').closest('.new').find('span4').length;"

Comment: sry $el.closest('.new').find('span4').length;

Comment: resolved. Eventually i used this: if ($('.new > div').length >= 3) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').insertAfter($row);
   }